# Can't set user permissions on directory

Tags: permissions

I keep getting a "permission denied" error on my /var/www/html/ via ftp.

Checking permissions (ls -l) on the directory has this output:

```
total 0
```

Yet, checking the permissions on 1 level above:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2   ftpuser   user_group   html
```

This appears to be right...

Why would I have two different ls -l outputs for the same directory?

Also, if I run WinSCP, I get Owner = 0 for the directory.

---

Here is the vsftpd.conf: http://codepad.org/CCfcyCnO

Here is the approved user_list. "alxvallejo" is what I added: http://codepad.org/XOHI4Icp

Currently, I can login only as root.

Comment: Which ftp daemon are you using ? What credentials are you logging in with and how do they relate to the permissions on the directory ?

Comment: I'm using vsftpd. The users are the same for when I login ftp and when I list permissions. The group is what throws me off...

Comment: Can you post as an edit to the question the contents of your vsftpd.conf please.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l` gives you the contents of the given directory. So when you do `ls -l /var/www/html/` it will give you the *contents* of /var/www/html/. If you want to see the directory itself do this: `ls -ld /var/www/html/`.

Also, keep in mind that your FTP daemon can have additional ACLs setup beyond the unix level user/group permissions. You may want to check the ftp configuration to make sure it allows writing to /var/www/html/.

Comment: hm, vsftpd.conf doesn't seem to list any directories at all in the file

Comment: Are you using the anonymous user?

Comment: anonymous_enable=NO

Comment: Have you tried uploading a file using SCP via WinSCP? Is there a reason you need ftp when scp and sftp is more secure? Permissions are much easier to fix and track down with those.

Comment: Ya, I get the same error in WinSCP. Keep in mind I'm binding the html folder to the home/ftpuser/ directory. That shouldn't matter since permissions are carried over.

Answer (score 0):

ls -l just lists of the contents of the working directory. Since the directory is empty, it returns total 0.

Since the wwww directory is in /var/www, a `ls -l` from /var/www is going to show you the permissions of the each file and directory in /var/www.

The command you want to run FROM /var/www/thml is `ls -ld`

Your ftp server might be configured to only permit uploads to a specific directory.